# Ionic - how to display business calendar on app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I use **Google Calendar** to manage the classes that I run at my school.

I'm developing an Ionic app and I want to be able to put my class times onto the customers' app so that they know when they're coming up. If I change the times of a class, I want the customers to see the update on their app.

Is there a way to integrate my Google Calendar with Ionic so that customer can see class times? Should I use a Google API with push notifications for instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to integrate Google Calendar with Ionic directly, but integrating using the default calendar app of the mobile device seems possible based on [this article](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/18/integrating-the-calendar-into-your-ionic-app/). It uses a [Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin) by Eddy Verbruggen. If your Google Calendar is linked to the Calendar app of the device, then I think its a great workaround.

Hopefully that article can be of help to you.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

As previously answered, you can go with the app "against" the local calendar, but you can also go directly to the Google calendar API accessing the very last centraliced version of the events. Just search the Google calendar API at Google developers site and use it. 
I prefer the second method to avoid inconsistencies. Let's say while offline two apps updates a previosly existing event. What happens? The second method is also "multiplatform" so in the future you want the app to run in Windows, iOS... the code is more reusable.
To provide offline access to the calendar events in a second phase I would store local copies of the selected user's calendars.
Method works with Ionic, Cordoba or native code.
I hope it will help you.